# How to pass value to the parameter using <input> tag

Tags: javascript, html

There is a problem with javascript in html. I created a function and with two parameters and want to pass the value to them using  tag instead of inside the code when the function is invoked.

i just did the traditional method.For example i created a function with two parameter on in a and b. and then i called the function and gave two values after that it worked as expected.
                but i don't want it, i want that these values can be given through the input box on the web page. and after that when the function is called somehow then it should return the result.

```
    <script>
    function sum(a,b)
    {
     return a+b;
    }
    var s = sum(4,5);
        document.write(s);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the code in an event handler, so that you don't call the function until after the user fills in the inputs. Then you use the `.value` property to get the values of the inputs.

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
document.getElementById("but").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("val1").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("val2").value);

  var s = sum(a, b);
  document.getElementById("output").innerText = s;
});
```

```html
Value 1: <input id="val1"><br> Value 2: <input id="val2"><br>
<button id="but">Compute</button><br> Result: <span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: One more question sir, is this the only way to do this with less complexity.
i understand that there would by a lots of methods to do this.

Comment: You can use a library like jQuery, it has simpler syntax like `$("#val1").val()`.

Comment: But you still need this general structure: listen for an event, get the values of the inputs, call the function, and show the result.

Comment: Yes that i know, this basic structure must.Thanks for considering sir.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you. You can adjust as necessary for your exact situation.

You can use `document.getElementById()` to identify each input, and then use the `value` property to get the typed value. Note also the use of `parseInt()` to turn the text input values into (whole) numbers (otherwise, you'd find that `3+2` would return `32` (joining the strings together) instead of `5` (adding the numbers)). Finally I've written the output back to another specific element on the page by settings its `innerText` property, rather than using the old-fashioned document.write().

All the functions I've used can easily be looked up in more detail online on sites such as MDN and others.

```js
var goBtn = document.getElementById("go");

//when button is clicked, grab the two input values and pass them to the function
goBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("input1").value);
  var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("input2").value);
  var result = sum(val1, val2);
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = result;
});

function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

```html
Input 1: <input type="number" id="input1" />
<br/>
Input 2: <input type="number" id="input2" />
<br/>
<button id="go" type="button">Go</button>
<br/><br/> Result:
<div id="result"></div>
```